# Sort by property in one-to-many association

Tags: grails, createcriteria

I have the following scenario (Domain classes)

```
class Request { 
    String title                
    List statusUpdates

    static hasMany = [statusUpdates: StatusUpdate]
}
```

and

```
class StatusUpdate {

    Date dateCreated
    String statusFrom
    String statusTo
    String notes

    static belongsTo = Request
}
```

I am currently using `createCriteria` to implement filtering and basic sorting of Request.

Now I want to get a list of `Request`s starting from the most recently updated (ordered by the value of the field `dateCreated` of the `last` `StatusUpdate` for the `Request`)

Any hint?

Comment: knock yourself out https://github.com/vahidhedayati/ajaxdependancyselection/blob/master/grails-app/services/ajaxdependancyselection/AutoCompleteService.groovy loads of examples here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that every Request has at least one StatusUpdate and slightly changing belongsTo declaration, you could go the other direction:

```
class StatusUpdate {

    Date dateCreated
    String statusFrom
    String statusTo
    String notes

    static belongsTo = [req: Request] // I assume that naming the field "request" would cause whole bunch of weird problems, therefore "req"
}

StatusUpdate.createCriteria().list() {
    req {
        // your criteria for requests filtering
    }
    projections {
        groupProperty 'req', 'reqAlias'
        max 'dateCreated', 'maxDateCreatedAlias'
    }
    order 'maxDateCreatedAlias', 'desc'
}.collect { it[0] }
```

Comment: Interesting approach, I did not think about this possibility. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Comparator or Comparable interface.
Here you have a nice example
[link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/)

Comment: Is this applicable if the instances are retrieved from a database (GORM) with other arbitrary criterias (filters)?